# Powershell regex - match until character

Tags: regex, powershell

So what I need to do is match text until I hit a certain character, then stop. Right now I'm having a heck of a time getting that to work right and at this point I think I'm just confusing myself even more. The text I'm searching will look like this:

```
ServerA_logfile.log
ServerB_logfile.log
ServerC_logfile.log
```

What I need to do is just return the server name, and exclude everything after the underscore character.

Here's my code:

```
Get-ChildItem \\fileshare\logs\ -Name -Filter *.log | foreach { [regex]::match($_ -replace "^_", "")}
```

What it returns is.... well, not helpful, but that's as good as I can get.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know regex was requested, but it would be just as easy (maybe easier) to use the built in `split` command.

Here is the code:

```
Get-ChildItem \\fileshare\logs\ -Name -Filter *.log | foreach { $_.Split("_")[0] }
```

Comment: Nice! I think I'll go this route. Not that I have anything against regex per se, but I would be able to figure this out much easier in the future. On a personal note, and maybe this is just me, but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel every time I go to re-learn regex, so an alternative is most welcome :)

Answer (score 6):

What you need is [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) (it's tailored to the *match before something* case)

```
[Regex]::Match($_, "^.+(?=_)").Value
```

`Match()` does not return a string, but a `Match` object. Hence the `Value` property should be accessed to extract the string from the object.

In case it wasn't clear, expression used specifies to find:

- at the beginning of line (`^`)
- string of any length (longer or equal to one character) (`.+`)
- followed by underscore (`(?=_)`), that's positive lookahead

Comment: Yup, and you could use Select-String with this e.g. `... | Select-String "(^.+)(?=_)" | Foreach {$_.Matches[0].Value}`

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I think I failed to mention that there are multiple underscore charters in the file name, so my output looks like "servername_logfile"... sorry about that. How do we stop at just the first underscore?

Comment: Change the regex to `(^.+?)(?=_)` so it isn't greedy.

Answer (score 3):

There is another very simple solution:

```
[Regex]::Match($_, "^[^_]*").Value
```

`[^_]` matches any character except underscores. Therefore `^[^_]*` starts the match at the start of the string and stops before the first underscore.