# rename files with powershell by deleting everything after the @ mark in the filename

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I have files named like
12420025@pa20s6gz@12420025_xxxgggopppxk.pdf

I want to rename them so that everything after the @ mark until the . and file extension are removed. So it would look like
12420025.pdf
I tried this but it gives an error. I cd'd to the directory in powershell and tried

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | Foreach-Object -Process { 
    $NewName = [Regex]::Match($@.Name,"^[^@]*").Value + '.pdf'
    $@ | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
```

but I am getting this error

```
At line:2 char:31
+     $NewName = [Regex]::Match($@.Name,"^[^@]*").Value + '.pdf'
+                               ~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:2 char:31
+     $NewName = [Regex]::Match($@.Name,"^[^@]*").Value + '.pdf'
+                               ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '$@.Name' in expression or statement.
At line:2 char:38
+     $NewName = [Regex]::Match($@.Name,"^[^@]*").Value + '.pdf'
+                                      ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At line:1 char:55
+ Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | Foreach-Object -Process {
+                                                       ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:2 char:47
+     $NewName = [Regex]::Match($@.Name,"^[^@]*").Value + '.pdf'
+                                               ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
```

Comment: You need to use the [automatic `$_` / `$PSItem` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) - `$@` doesn't work in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gci -Filter *.pdf|foreach {
    $newname="{0}.pdf" -f ([regex]'(^.+?)(?=@)').Match($_.Name).Value
    $_|Rename-Item -NewName $newname
}
```

Wish I could give you a good explanation about regex but is not my strong point, I just went here and read: [Powershell regex - match until character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410397/powershell-regex-match-until-character)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly less complicated approach:

```
$SourcePath = "G:\Test\PDFS\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -File  -Filter *@*.pdf |
  Foreach-Object { 
    $LenCut  = $_.BaseName.Indexof('@')
    $NewName = $_.BaseName.Substring(0,$LenCut).Trim() + 
               $_.Extension
    $_.FullName | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
  }
```

Advantages:

- Will only select files.
- Will not cause errors if you feed it a file that does not contain a @.
- Squashes trailing spaces in file name after trimming.
- Easier to understand.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can make this very concise with a better filter, a delayed bind scriptblock, and a little bit of regex.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *@*.pdf -File |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '@.+(?=\.)'}
```

A potential problem is duplicate file names. This code does not take that into account.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `delayed bind script block`? Have heard it hear about twice now just not sure if it's just a fancy term for the script block on the other end of the pipeline?

Comment: Yes that’s exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this actually  [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) and it did the job. I have no idea if it is safe but it worked. If anyone knows it is not safe please let me know.